# PHP String Comparison With str_replace not working

Tags: php, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare a few strings to execute an if statement. I've tried a few ways around using `str_replace` and `trim` to remove all white spaces but it does not work when there are several words. Any suggestion? Thanks.

string

```
//check company industry
$checkcompanyq = "SELECT type,id,employee_id FROM company";
$checkcompanyresult = mysqli_query($db, $checkcompanyq);
$companyassoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkcompanyresult);
$companyindustry = $companyassoc['type'];
$comindustrynospace  = str_replace(' ','',$companyindustry);
```

It works when it's a single word. This string will work and if statement execute

```
if($comindustrynospace=="Insurance"){
//do something
}
```

It does not work when several words. This string wont work and if statement wont execute

```
 if($comindustrynospace=="RealEstate&Rental"){
    //do something
    }
```

I tried with trim but does not execute either

```
 if(trim($comindustrynospace)==trim("RealEstate&Rental")){
        //do something
        }
```

This is what $companyindustry looks like before `str_replace`

```
$companyindustry = 'Real Estate & Rental';
```

Comment: Try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

Comment: Can you past the whole `$companyindustry` string?

Comment: str_replace is working fine please try to echo **$comindustrynospace** var

Comment: @SaadSuri: You mean paste the query?

Comment: @PrateikDarji: The $comindustrynospace var is being printed inside input and I see its there its working.

Comment: @Clark post a potential value for $comindustrynospace for the second condition. before running str_replace on it

Comment: it is working as it should work, I don't find where you get an error if you are using str_replace for removing spaces then it's removing, please provide your code with output where it is not working.

Comment: @AmilaDev: I just made an edit

Comment: @Clark I just tested your code and it worked fine for me. I didn't even use trim()

Comment: @AmilaDev: something very strange happens when I test with a different if statement. So I tested this `if($comindustrynospace=="Insurance"){
echo $comindustrynospace;
}` Now what happens is it will print `Insurance` for every single while iteration which is weird because not all variables are Insurance. On some of them it should return nothing.

Comment: @Clark how do you assign values to the $companyindustry variable? From where does it get the values?

Comment: @AmilaDev; I have updated my question.

Comment: @AmilaDev: I found the problem for some reason my program does not recognize anything after this `&` so I will just compare the first word of each string to solve this. thanks for your time.

Comment: @Clark great. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. You should check `$comindustrynospace` and the value you want to compare with.

```
$companyindustry=" My Insurance ";
$comindustrynospace = str_replace(' ','',$companyindustry);

echo $comindustrynospace;

if($comindustrynospace=="MyInsurance"){
//do something
  echo " <br>Insurance work";
}
```